# AngularJS : Define timezone to UTC globally?

Tags: angularjs, date

Is it possible to define timezone to UTC for the whole AngularJs application ?

I would like to avoid setting the attribute

```
    ng-model-options="{timezone: 'UTC'}"
```

because I have to define it, each time that I have to declare an input date

```
    <input type="date" ng-model="value" ng-model-options="{timezone: 'UTC'}">
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should consider creating a custom directive for this, basically you encapsulate this logic within a directive and use the custom directive across your application wherever you need a date input, [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/0QkHPSFqNGnADYCy87tp?p=preview) is a demonstration on plunkr!!

```
app.directive('utcdateInput',function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        template:'<input type="date" ng-model="value" ng-model-options="{timezone: """UTC"""}">'
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!!